# Hose bib manufacturer

Tags: spigot

Can anyone please identify the manufacturer of this hose bib so I can get the correct vacuum breaker. Thanks.

[image: Hose Bib]
[image: vacuum breaker threads]

Comment: Have you been to local hardware stores?  After trying to figure this out on my own house, I was pleasantly surprised to find them stocked at the ACE hardware in my area specifically because builders at the time most of the houses were built used the same brand and a lot of people would come in looking for them.

Comment: I have been to 4 places including Ace and it is bigger than what they have. Thanks

Comment: Make the fifth your last: just buy a whole new thing. That would've been my go-to. It's two screws and a sweat job. And then it's w/e the new manufacturer-is's problem when it breaks, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a ProPlus to me. The molded box with the #2 is pretty unusual. From the pictures I saw, I would guess the handle is not original.

Examples:

[https://www.amazon.com/PROPLUS-262024-Anti-Siphon-Frost-Proof-Sillcock/dp/B00PM8ZGNG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PM8ZGNG)

https://www.walmart.com/ip/ProPlus-Anti-Siphon-Sillcock/38289469

Comment: Thank you so much! That does look like the cap on mine as well.